# Crystal report using C#

Tags: crystal-reports

Am beginner in crystal report and creating application in Crystal Reports in that

sample Box Object below

```
-----------------------
|Name | column1       |
|---------------------|
|text | column2       |
|---------------------|
|Remark| column3      |
----------------------
```

Note: column4 is contain true or false

if cloumn4 is true means Box should be visible false means invisible

table with sample data

```
col1 | col2| col3 | col4
-------------------------
abc  |abc  |abc   |true
def  |def  |def   |false
xyz  |xyz  |xyz   |false
xyz  |xyz  |xyz   |true
```

I want to print like

```
box1             (invisible)
(invisible)     box4
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

in crystal report you can use suppress to make objects invisible

```
Format Field -> Common -> suppress Button
```

and you can use this example in suppress formula:

```
if col4 = true then false else true;
```